# Does the rewards on the pledge stake address count toward the stake pool pledge?

Tags: stake-pool, rewards, pledge

The pledge is just a delegation to the stake pool signed with the owner key. My question about the pledge amount, are the stake address' rewards counting towards the stake pool pledge as well or just the UTxO funds on their associated addresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, (UTxO + stake rewards) constitute the total stake. So the rewards are part of the pledge. One confirmation would be nice !

Comment: it should count, but can someone confirm that?